# How to pass variable from textbox to code behind back to same page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a webs form page and I have a text box which once clicked passes a variable to the code behind and then back into another element of that page and I cannot get it to work.
This is the closest I have got.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Search" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valSearch" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="movieSearch" Text="Please enter text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" 
                OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResult" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <script>
        var search = '<%=Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Data"]) %>';
    </script>
</asp:Panel>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        pnlSearch.Visible = false;
        pnlSearchResult.Visible = true;
        Response.Redirect("search.aspx?Data=" + Server.UrlEncode(search.Text));
    }
}
```

Also this does not change the visibility of the two panels for some reason.

I would appreciate any guidance I am very new to asp and c#.

Comment: Is that necessary to use `Response.Redirect` for the same page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The panel's visibility is not changing because you're forcing a new GET request to the page with this: -

```
Response.Redirect("search.aspx?Data=" + Server.UrlEncode(search.Text));
```

(I'm assuming your page is called 'search.aspx')

There's no need to do this. Remove this line.

Secondly, I see you want to force the textbox's Text value into a Javascript variable. Replace this

```
var search = '<%=Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Data"]) %>';
```

with this

```
var search = '<%= search.Text %>';
```

Comment: No worries friend :) You should read up on how the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle and Postback mechanisms work

Answer (score 0):

Write below code on page event.
Another more important point is you first panel Id is "Search" not "pnlSearch" on aspx page so please correct it

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                   {

                    if (Request.QueryString["Data"] != null)
                       {
                            Search.Visible = false;
                          pnlSearchResult.Visible = true;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend solution without using `Response.Redirect`.

Code Behind `Submit` Button click:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsValid)
    {
        pnlSearch.Visible = false;
        pnlSearchResult.Visible = true;           
    }
}
```

In Markup:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSearchResult" runat="server" Visible="false">
   <script> 

    var searchTxt = document.getElementById('search');

            if(searchTxt.value != null && searchTxt.value != ''){
               //do your stuff
            }

   </script>
```